# A sufficient condition for non existance of hamiltonian cycle

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-paths

I think i have a sufficient condition for non existance of hamiltonian cycle in a graph, I want to check if it has already been found, I tried googling for it and didnt find anything so far, how can i go about finding out if this condition is new?

Comment: You could write what it is in this post so that people on here could help....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is kind of vague, and I don't know of a comprehensive listing of necessary conditions for Hamiltonicity (or equivalently sufficient conditions for non-Hamiltonicity). But for one such condition, commonly used to prove non-Hamiltonicity of certain planar graphs, see [Grinberg's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grinberg%27s_theorem).

Another necessary condition, valid for all graphs (not just planar graphs), is that a Hamiltonian graph must be [1-tough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_toughness). So if you can find a set of $k$ vertices whose removal disconnects the remaining graph into more than $k$ pieces, it's not Hamiltonian.

Comment: Thanks david, i now realise that the condition i thought about was already found and it is exactly what you mentioned in your answer about 1-toughness. nice!